# Script to stop tomcat server works intermittently

Tags: linux, tomcat

I am very much new to linux and to this forum. I am working on one issue for a customer where they have 10+ Red Hat Linux 5.5 64 bits servers. They want to stop the tomcat process using the stop script (the script uses 'kill -15')
On some servers, the script works fine and stops the tomcat process within seconds.
On some servers, sometimes it stops quickly, sometimes it keeps running for minutes and finally customer has to use 'kill -9' command to stop tomcat. Logs are not indicating anything.

Do you have any idea why there is an intermittent behaviour of this script? How can we catch it in logs etc?

Answer (score 0):

Processes may ignore the `SIGTERM(15)` signal.

From Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal

> The SIGTERM signal is sent to a process to request its termination. Unlike the SIGKILL signal, it can be caught and interpreted or ignored by the process. This allows the process to perform nice termination releasing resources and saving state if appropriate.

If it's ignored the only option left is to kill it with `SIGKILL(9)` which can't be ignored.